# Razor helper not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to add a Razor helper, but cannot get the view to recognise it.

I've got the simplest of all helpers...

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace CharityVouchers.Web.Helpers {
  public static class Razorhelper {
    public static string Jim(this HtmlHelper helper) {
      return "Jim";
    }
  }
}
```

If I go to my _Layout.cshtml, and add the following at the top...

```
@using CharityVouchers.Web.Helpers
```

...and then try to use my helper lower down the file, I don't get Intellisense when I hit the period after "Html" and if I enter the method name manually, it's shown in red and I get an error message.

```
@Html.Jim()
```

The error message is...

*CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Jim' and no extension method 'Jim' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I've tried everything I can find, but nothing seems to help. Anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** Forgot to mention that I tried adding the namespace to Web.config, both the main one and the one in Views, but it didn't make any difference. As I have the using in the view it shouldn't have made any difference, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as I've tried your code in a html helper extension this side and it built OK, with the web.config method in my answer.

Comment: Is your project compiling without errors?

Comment: Ho hum, it turned out that the helper class file had somehow been excluded from the project (don't ask me how, I'd only just added it), and so wasn't being included in the compile. I did a "Show all files" included and it rebuilt, and it all works! Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In the `web.config` in the Views folder, add your html helper namespace `<add namespace="CharityVouchers.Web.Helpers" />` in. E.g.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html5" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="CharityVouchers.Web.Helpers" />       
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This is the result I got using your code -

[image]

Is your `CharityVouchers.Web.Helpers` namespace in the same project as your MVC site or definitely in an included DLL?

Another difference I've noticed (and may just be your cut and paste of code), is that I needed to add `using System.Web.Mvc;` instead of `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;` in the class.

Comment: This is the clean way to do it, however the OP has the necessary '@using' in his view. So it should work without adding it to the web.config. That is assuming the helper is called within the same view of course.

Comment: @NikolaiDante Thanks for the reply, but as I mentioned in my question, I added the using to the view itself (yes Franky, it was the same view). I forgot to add in my question that I'd tried adding it to the web.config, both the main one and the one in Views, so that's not the problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

double check your web.config in the Views folder to ensure that the correct namespaces are available:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
```

Comment: Please see my reply to NikolaiDante